# Mobile site does not have Winter Bash pulldown in notification bar

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

There is no snowflake on the mobile site, and there does not appear to be any other way to see Winter Bash notifications.

[image]

Workaround is to switch to desktop site on mobile to check.

Comment: Mobile web just plain doesn't have Winterbash.

Comment: @animuson Don't get sassy with me.

Comment: @JasonC I suggest you edit the post, to make it more clear it is a feature-request. I suggest to add: "Can we have hat notifications in the mobile site?" And perhaps emphasize that it's only about hat _notifications_, as hats themselves are apparently too heavy for the mobile site.

Comment: @S.L. Since the title and text already talk about notifications and nothing else, and since it is tagged as a feature request, I'm not sure what else I could do. There is literally an infinite list of things this post isn't about, unfortunately I cannot add them all.